# wlan: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, driver

I am trying to compile the wlan driver for my Kernel for my Xiaomi Mi4i.
I am able to successfully compile the `wlan.ko` file.

I'm also using the same kernel on my phone against which I've compiled this module.
Even then I'm not able to insmod this kernel module.
When I do insmod, I get the following error :

```
insmod: init_module 'wlan.ko' failed (Exec format error)
```

And, inside dmesg I get the following output :

```
<4>[  851.333053] wlan: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

Any idea what might be going wrong ?
Also, is there any way I can disable this versioning check all together ?

Edit: Just realized this is not the problem only for this wlan module. I'm not able to load any .ko module at all.

Comment: You compiled for the wrong kernel (or using wrong kernel sources).

Comment: @omerjerk, you should load **same** kernel, against which you compile module. Loading *different* kernel with same kernel version is not sufficient.

Comment: Both the versions are same. I've made sure that already. Problem is with something else. Probably something wrong with kernel config.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Makefile will pick other source directory which we were not intended.
Please check that there any environment variables set.
Otherwise, while compiling driver, please pin point sources as well.
This will ensure that you have compiled to proper sources and module symbols.

- Thank You